# How to force Linux users to respect max login rate

Tags: ssh, rate-limiting, throttling

How does one set a rate-based throttle and/or quota for SSH logins per user on a shared system? For example: limit an SSH login to one time per 10 seconds.

Things I've looked at:

- pam throttle and throttle2, but those look for failed logins and then throttle. I instead want to look for successful logins and then throttle.
- fail2ban, but that blocks IPS/ranges as opposed to users, which does not help me here. (EDITED to note IP vs user blocks)

Comment: An SSH login every two seconds would not kill a server unless it is already overloaded. In other words, focus on the best problems to solve. Make sure you are actually benefiting everyone by trying to block a script. I suggest you have a meeting with the person responsible for the script to choose a more manageable solution. Blocking a script that provides a valuable service might be the wrong direction. No matter which direction you choose, each method will have a CPU cost (cost to log in, cost to monitor traffic to block logins).

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for your comment. You are right, talking to a problem user is a good first course of action. That said I was very interested to notice that I could find no generalized throttling information for SSH, save for failed logins/fail2ban type situation. I am wondering how this is done for large-scale shared hosting providers. Are there any guides like this? I have edited the question to generalize accordingly, and de-emphasize my specific current symptoms.

Comment: In development, I often do things like SSH login over and over. I have never been throttled or rate limited for valid connections at any vendor. As I mentioned, successful logins every two seconds consume a small amount of total CPU time - apx 10 ms on modern i7 type CPUs. IHMO, you are worried about a problem that might not need to be solved thru rate limiting. Failed connections are a different matter.

Comment: This is a valid question. My hosting service has a large number of customers. Occasionally there are customers with misconfigured script that do hundreds of successful logins per second.

Answer (score 2):

`fail2ban` allows custom filters and custom actions. You can create a custom filter to parse appropriate logs for successful ssh login with appropriate action.

You can find many examples of different filters in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/` and many examples of different actions in `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/`

If you don't want to use IP blocking then you can lock a user account with `passwd -l username`. Or you can create a script `/bin/sshratelimit` which prints some strongly worded warning and set this script as the user's shell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was under the impression that fail2ban only does IP based blocking/firewall control. I can't find any info about blocking/unblocking accounts. Am I missing something? I'll also clarify the question to note that IP blocking won't work in my case.

Comment: @EdwardTeach I have updated the answer.